# Why loading a python module appears to uninstall modules?

Tags: python, module, installation, progress

I load the `progress` module alongside others and suddenly it somehow removes itself from my installation, even with restarting python it's gone. How is this happening? I've since become frustrated and moved to a different progress bar library (of the many), but I'd still like to know what's going on.

Python versions attempted: custom built python3.6; miniconda python3.6.

After `pip install progress` in either environment, I run these 2 scripts:

```
## script 1 (run on CLI: python script1.py)
from progress.bar import Bar
```

Script 1 runs okay. So I try script 2:

```
## script 2 (run on CLI: python script2.py)
import argparse
import os
import sys
import glob
import pandas
from progress.bar import Bar
```

which results in the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'progress.bar'; 'progress' is not a package`
and now script 1 produces the same error. Reinstalling progress through pip does not allow script 1 to run again. I must install progress from source `python setup.py build && python setup.py install` for script 1 to run again. Script 2 consistently appears to destroy the installation. What in the world is going on here?

UPDATED well 3rd installation is a charm. Seems to work now. It must have been one of those spurious errors that only exists for 1 hour at a time. Thanks for looking.

Comment: More comprehensive log output will be useful for the rest of us to actually see the issues, as with just this information reproduction of the problem cannot be done.

Comment: @metatoaster Do you have an idea what log file I should be looking at? I've never come across this in the context of python and I must not be using the right search words. I'll put together a MWE from clean install to error and update my question.

Comment: Is `script2` actually named `progress`?

Comment: @internet_user No, it's named script2.py. This also happens in REPL mode so it's filename independent.

Comment: By log output I meant the complete Traceback, plus whatever you saw in the console when you executed those commands (e.g. pip install) manually.